# oracle.sql.CLOB vs java.sql.Clob

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, clob, java-6

I'm currently using `oracle.sql.CLOB` to bind to Oracle Clob.

Are there any benefits of using

```
java.sql.Clob clob = con.createClob();
```

instead of creating a temporary Clob using

```
oracle.oracle.sql.CLOB.createTemporary(oracleConn, false, oracle.sql.CLOB.DURATION_SESSION);
```

We are using Java 6.

Comment: Java 6?  You should upgrade to JDK 8 or better immediately.  JDK 12 is current production.  You should be using java.sql.Clob and not tying yourself to Oracle.  You should always prefer the interface classes, not concrete implementations.

Answer (score 5):

[oracle.sql.CLOB](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/CLOB.html) **class** deprecated for using `java.sql.Clob` **interface**:

> Deprecated. Use java.sql.Clob interface for declaration instead of using concrete class oracle.sql.CLOB.

Interface is available since Java 1.2

See also Oracle's [Using Large Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html)

> ```
> Clob myClob = this.con.createClob();
> ```